# flatmapping a nested Map in scala

Tags: scala, hashmap

Suppose I have `val someMap = Map[String -> Map[String -> String]]` defined as such:

```
val someMap = 
Map( 
    ("a1" -> Map( ("b1" -> "c1"), ("b2" -> "c2") ) ),
    ("a2" -> Map( ("b3" -> "c3"), ("b4" -> "c4") ) ),
    ("a3" -> Map( ("b5" -> "c5"), ("b6" -> "c6") ) )   
)
```

and I would like to flatten it to something that looks like

```
List(   
    ("a1","b1","c1"),("a1","b2","c2"),
    ("a2","b3","c3"),("a2","b4","c4"),
    ("a3","b5","c5"),("a3","b6","c6")
)
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this? I was thinking about creating some helper function that processes each `(a_i -> Map(String,String))` key value pair and return

```
def helper(key: String, values: Map[String -> String]): (String,String,String) 
= {val sublist = values.map(x => (key,x._1,x._2))
return sublist
}
```

then flatmap this function over `someMap`. But this seems somewhat unnecessary to my novice scala eyes, so I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to parse this Map.

Comment: You mean something like `someMap.flatMap { case (a, m) => m.map { case (b, c) => (a, b, c) } }`?

Comment: Or `for { (a, m) <- someMap; (b,c) <- m } yield (a,b,c)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to create helper function just write nested lambda:

```scala
val result = someMap.flatMap { case (k, v) => v.map { case (k1, v1) => (k, k1, v1) } }
```

Or

```scala
val y = someMap.flatMap(x => x._2.map(y => (x._1, y._1, y._2)))
```

Comment: Maybe `flatMap` instead of `flatten`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez why?

Comment: Because it works for wrong reasons: `def flatten[B](implicit asIterable: A => scala.collection.IterableOnce[B]): CC[B]` - you passed lambda as explicitly passed implicit which should be used to turn "nested map" into "flattened map" and accidentally it compiled and returned `IterableOnce` (instead of Map or List). In general case you cannot trust this, and this is a hack that abuses the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're asking about efficiency, the most efficient yet functional approach I can think of is using `foldLeft` and `foldRight`.

You need `foldRight` since `::` constructs the immutable list in reverse.

```scala
someMap.foldRight(List.empty[(String, String, String)]) { case ((a, m), acc)  =>
  m.foldRight(acc) {
    case ((b, c), acc) => (a, b, c) :: acc
  }
}
```

Here, assuming `Map.iterator.reverse` is implemented efficiently, no intermediate collections are created.

Alternatively, you can use `foldLeft` and then `reverse` the result:

```
someMap.foldLeft(List.empty[(String, String, String)]) { case (acc, (a, m))  =>
  m.foldLeft(acc) {
    case (acc, (b, c)) => (a, b, c) :: acc
  }
}.reverse
```

This way a single intermediate `List` is created, but you don't rely on the implementation of the reversed iterator (`foldLeft` uses forward iterator).

---

Note: one liners, such as `someMap.flatMap(x => x._2.map(y => (x._1, y._1, y._2)))` are less efficient, as, in addition to the temporary buffer to hold intermediate results of `flatMap`, they create and discard additional intermediate collections for each inner `map`.

---

**UPD**

Since there seems to be some confusion, I'll clarify what I mean. Here is an implementation of `map`, `flatMap`, `foldLeft` and `foldRight` from `TraversibleLike`:

```scala
  def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
    def builder = { // extracted to keep method size under 35 bytes, so that it can be JIT-inlined
      val b = bf(repr)
      b.sizeHint(this)
      b
    }
    val b = builder
    for (x <- this) b += f(x)
    b.result
  }

  def flatMap[B, That](f: A => GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
    def builder = bf(repr) // extracted to keep method size under 35 bytes, so that it can be JIT-inlined
    val b = builder
    for (x <- this) b ++= f(x).seq
    b.result
  }

  def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = {
    var result = z
    this foreach (x => result = op(result, x))
    result
  }

  def foldRight[B](z: B)(op: (A, B) => B): B =
    reversed.foldLeft(z)((x, y) => op(y, x))
```

It's clear that `map` and `flatMap` create intermediate buffer using corresponding `builder`, while `foldLeft` and `foldRight` reuse the same user-supplied accumulator object, and only use iterators.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you for pointing out about `List.empty`. Although, here, since it's called only once, it doesn't matter. However, I disagree with you, regarding `flatMap` vs `foldRight`.  `foldRight` uses iterators and doesn't create any intermediate collections at all, while `flatMap` creates buffer for its results, and also every inner `map` call creates its own buffer.

Comment: Check this: `someMap.iterator.flatMap(x => x._2.iterator.map(y => (x._1, y._1, y._2))).toList` - Althought you were right about the intermediate collections I misunderstood your point.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, gotcha. `toList` here still uses an intermediate mutable buffer and `foldRight` will be more efficient, if `iterator.reversed` of the particular `Map` implementation is as efficient as forward iterator, but I agree, your approach would be effectively the same, if not better, than `foldLeft + reverse`.